# How to get all domains on server using PHP?

Tags: ip, reverse

Im working on a small php script and i want to add a feature that allow visitors to get all domains hosted on a server . But i don't know how to do it with php .

Answer (score 0):

You do not tell many details...

Try `system("ls /var/www/directory/with/domains")`
Of course, you must have privileges.

I do not know if I understand your problem.

Comment: I want to get all domains on another server

Comment: It's probably not possible. Maybe other people know solution, I think it's impossible because it maybe a security hole in other server.